# Errors during npm install or yarn install ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, enoent

I get a lot of errors when I run npm install or yarn install (basically the same error). The relevant part of the error message is:

```
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/.cache/yarn/v6/.tmp/64eb75e6f1c0c61ed8c4337dfb1a7c31.8da6f05825b42e9d85cb82e05a122aa7d75f1846.prepare/node_modules/d3-array/build/d3-array.min.js'
In module tree:
    openmct
      src/defaultRegistry
        platform/features/conductor/core/bundle
          platform/features/conductor/core/src/ui/ConductorAxisController


events.js:170
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/.cache/yarn/v6/.tmp/64eb75e6f1c0c61ed8c4337dfb1a7c31.8da6f05825b42e9d85cb82e05a122aa7d75f1846.prepare/node_modules/d3-array/build/d3-array.min.js'
In module tree:
    openmct
      src/defaultRegistry
        platform/features/conductor/core/bundle
          platform/features/conductor/core/src/ui/ConductorAxisController

    at Object.openSync (fs.js:448:3)
```

Any ideas what could cause this error? I already had to downgrade node to version 11 because everything more recent returns a 'primordials is not defined' error. npm install returns a similar ENOENT error.

Comment: I'd try my luck in [npm issues](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues?q=is%3Aissue+ENOENT) or [yarn issues](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues?q=is%3Aissue+ENOENT).

Comment: The place is pretty dead. Someone already noted that there were many build issues but did not get a response yet. (they posted a couple of months ago)
But it seemed like a pretty general error, so I thought I'd try my luck here.